# What is 'draw on'

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101309/what-is-draw-on) was asked earlier (not by me), but closed and deleted by a mod. But I thought it was interesting, because I didn't know the answer. So I'm reposting it....

---

The verb phrasal 'draw on' seems to have two conflicting definitions:

> [dictionary 1](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/draw)
>   to come closer in time
>   "It became colder as night drew on."
>
> [dictionary 2](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/draw?q=draw)
>   (of a period of time) pass by and approach its end:
>   "he remembered sitting in silence with his grandmother as evening drew on"

How is 'draw on' used by native speakers?

---

...that's the original. Here's my own additional research from OED:

> **draw** B.VI.70 *To draw near or approach in time.*
>
> **draw in** B.VII.82.f *Of a day or evening: To draw to a close, to close in. Also of a succession of evenings in late summer and autumn: To become gradually shorter (as if contracting or shrinking in).*
>
> **draw on** B.VII.86.d *To advance, approach, draw nigh.*
>    86.e *To draw near to death, be in a dying state.*

So, to restate the original question, which of these does *as night drew on* mean? (I've no idea!)

> 1 *as night approached*
>   2 *as night passed*
>   3 *as night drew to a close*

Comment: We probably need more context to answer the question. This comes from a narrative of some kind. What time is it in the narrative? What's the narrator describing other than the fall in temperature? My feeling is that the default meaning is #1: the temperature always drops as the sun sinks slowly below the horizon. #2 is also possible. #3 is, for me, the least likely. I base this response solely on my decades of reading novels, short stories, poems, and other types of narratives. It's ambiguous, but context should make it clear.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I don't follow you. I'm asking what *night drawing on* means, having suggested three possibilities. If the answer is "all of them, depending on what the speaker/writer intends at the time", just say so. Or maybe tell me that of [100,000](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22night+drew+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) written instances of *"night drew on"*, the meaning changes according to how long ago it was written. I don't know!

Comment: M-W (dictionary 1) and OED B.VII.86. (based on B.VI.70) are practically identical, and the sense called for here; OED 86e is just a metaphorical extension. Oxford (dictionary 2) is about *evening* in the sense "twilight before night") not *night*, so irrelevant here (and that *by* is ambiguous). OED B.VII.82.f is, likewise, about *day* or *evening*; and is in any case a different phrase.

Comment: @StoneyB: So [this one](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vl1w58EQbJoC&pg=PA139&dq=%22night+drew+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0bYAUdG7KuKm0QWtiYHYDA&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=%22night%20drew%20on%22&f=false) is an "incorrect" usage? It says *But as the sultry night drew on **toward one o'clock**, Bill Day and his party felt their spirits revive a little.* How can night be *approaching* at one o'clock?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you're misparsing. Not "It's approximately one o'clock, and night is approaching us" but "Night is moving toward [i.e., approaching] one o'clock."

Comment: ...the fact that OP's Dict2 happens to use *evening* rather than *night* is the irrelevant factor! That definition says **of a period of time**, which could be afternoon, morning, whatever.

Comment: @StoneyB: I can't see that. It seems to me it means *night passed* (and continued passing until it was getting near to one o'clock).

Comment: @Fu: I **did say** that it depends on what the writer intended at the time: context. What's the situation in the narrative? Most of the time, it's safe to assume that "as night drew on" means #1, "as night approached", but context can change that. At midnight, even though it's technically morning, the words refer to the blackness of the sky, the lack of sunlight, which means that it's still "the middle of the night", so it'll mean "as the night passed", but then it should probably be "as **the** night drew on". For #3, it should probably be "as night drew on to morning".

Comment: @Bill Franke: Effectively, then, it means 1, 2, *and* [maybe] 3, in descending order of likelihood. But my guess is any given speaker/writer would be unlikely to use it in more than one sense, since that would often give scope for ambiguity. Figuring out which of multiple possibilities was intended *after the utterance* is a whole nother ball game to deciding what phrasing to use *for a specific intended meaning*.

Comment: @Fu: Yes, you've got it now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These definitions and examples (except *draw in*, which is a somewhat different idiom) have a common theme:

- It grew colder as night drew on ... *as nightfall came closer and closer*
- sitting in silence with his grandmother as evening drew on ... *as evening advanced toward nightfall*
- the sultry night drew on toward one o'clock ... *progressed gradually toward one o'clock*
- He lay (as some say) drawing on Untill his breath and all were past and gone ... *(this is a citation for OED 86.3) he lingered on his deathbed until he died*

I think it's fair to say that *draw on* means, at bottom, “advance gradually”—usually with a sense of advancing inexorably, too, and often toward some goal, implicit or explicit. The finer distinctions are just imaginative ways people have found to employ the phrase.

And it should be noted that these are just the intransitive uses; OED also distinguishes three transitives (none very closely related to the intransitives).

But given that OED offers 70-some-odd different meanings of bare *draw*, perhaps we should be surprised that *draw on* has so few.

At any rate, in my experience, *night drew on* is usually a stock phrase for “night gradually approached”—it got darker and darker. But it **might** mean any of those other things, too.

Comment: I think there's a bit of "trickery" going on when you conflate *approaching* with what's effectively *drawing to a close*, in, for example, [evening drew on and darkness (fell)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22evening+drew+on+and+darkness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). It seems to me these are quite distinct meanings. I don't use *night draws on* for any of the three senses I put forward, but it seems obvious others do. Perhaps the question is - would any *one* speaker use it in all three senses?

Comment: ...OED notwithstanding, the fourth example there reads to me more like a variant of *to draw breath*, rather than *draw near to death*. But it's only "as some say", and presumably it's a very old citation, so my modern-day parsing is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Well, apparently nobody's used it in the deathbed sense since the 17th century. The other two? Sure. It's how Time works. If you're speaking about something in the future, it's *drawing on* towards its beginning. If you're talking about something you're in now, it's *drawing on* towards its end. (But if you're talking about something in the past, and it's non-cyclic, it's not *drawing on* at all - it's *drawing away*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  In the 16th-17th centuries, *draw* still had mostly its original sense of "pull" = "drag" (same word), so the deathbed sense had a feel of laboring onward - we still say "dragging on", "time drags".

Comment: Yes, I'd quite happily say *as the night **dragged** on* myself, to mean *the time passed*. But time *dragging* is invariably *tedious/negative*, and I'd probably use ***slipped** along/away* for neutral/positive contexts if I didn't actually stick with *passed*..

Comment: On balance it does seem *approached* is a more common sense than *elapsed/passed*. I never thought the question was particularly interesting, or likely to have a definitive "single correct meaning" answer. I mainly asked it because I've been ticked off by mods for calling attention to posts by the original OP (a troll). I couldn't see any good reason for retaining many of his questions that are even less useful than this one, so when I saw it was deleted I reposted it (and eventually figured out how to make it Community Wiki! :)

Answer (score 3):

To *draw* in this sense means

> [*to come or go steadily or gradually*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw)

*Night draws on* is not ambiguous and means it is currently night and nighttime we continue to progress through the nighttime period.  You can add '*to a close*' if you specifically want to point out that it's getting toward morning.

*Night draws [near/nigh]* means it is not currently night, but nighttime approaches.  One might also say it is *drawing toward night* to indicate nighttime approaches.

It all comes from *draw's* base meaning of [*to pull*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw), as night (or time in general) is pulled along inexorably.

Comment: also "to drag on", from your link.

Comment: I agree with this explanation, and can offer this exercise. Construct a sentence with one of the other listed possible definitions for _as night drew on_ (for example, for #1: _The boys had to cut their game short as night approached, and the horizons darkened._). Then, ask yourself, if I substituted _as night drew on_, would the sentence retain its original meaning? (In this example, I'd wouldn't think so – I'd want to stick with _as night approached_ or _as night drew near_, as Jim said in his answer.)

Comment: Looking at instances of [as (the) night drew on](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+the+night+drew+on%2Cas+night+drew+on&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) It's not usually easy to make a positive distinction between the *approached* and *progressed* senses. But after spending a few minutes with it, I can't see an overwhelming bias for one meaning or the other in those cases where I *can* be reasonably sure of the intended sense. Nor do I see any shift over time, or a UK/US usage difference. But there's no doubt both meanings are in fact used.

Answer (score 0):

I am being drawn in by the wickedness that lurks beyond the dusk. That wickedness is irresistible. It is pulling me in and seducing me with its suggestive whisper.

Night is fallen and, somehow, we are still waiting! I am growing impatient, with my lust being drawn across the chilly air, just as the night was drawing itself slowly and painfully, pulling and dragging itself that I could feel its anxiety.

As the night drew on, dragging itself in such manner, even as midnight drew by, I could barely any no longer withstand the stench of its anxiety.

I could not believe that I let myself being drawn into such occult.

I am drawing on the experience of my spirit guide. I am riding on her experience. I depend on her to show me the way to the wicked scene. That is because there is no experience of my own that I could draw from.

Just as the night seemed to be drawing down and hints of early morn appeared from across the horizon of the ocean, there we saw the occultation of the turtles laying their eggs underneath the sand.

"That was wicked cool", I whispered to my spirit guide, an experienced zoologist specialising in sea turtles.

Comment: You drew it on yourself. If you'd drawn on your coat, the night wouldn't have been so chilly.

Comment: I'd have thought the fact that I cited OED definitions going up to 86 would be a good indication that there's no point in trying to illustrate all the possible usages of *draw* (you've barely scratched the surface, btw! :) Anyway, I asked about the meaning of *one specific phrase*; you haven't directly answered the question, and you've introduced a lot of irrelevant confusion, so -1.

Comment: sorry @BlessedGeek, that was fun, but not an answer

Answer (score -1):

"as night drew on" - you can't tell
It either means as night approaches (more common) or as the night progressed.

If you are committing poetry - who cares?
If you are writing an accident report you should probably pick a less ambiguous, if less poetic, phrase.

Comment: I asked about *as night drew **on***, so I hope that was a typo. But I'm still downvoting because I don't see this answer as being particularly informative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the fact is that it could mean either. Not quite as bad as flammable/inflammable - but that's English for you!

Comment: If it can have two meanings, what about three? Can *draw on* be used to mean *draw to a close* too?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It could. Context is everything: if it's four o'clock in the morning, it means *draw to a close*, if it's four o'clock in the evening, it means *drawing towards us*. But the default cliché, if you just encounter the bare phrase, is the latter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - just ot add to the confusion "as the nights draw in" means the days are getting shorter ie, going into winter.

Comment: That *getting shorter* sense is in my second OED definition - it's the only one where I know for sure exactly what it means, because I say and hear it all the time in late summer/early autumn. But that usage is always in the plural, so I didn't include it as a possible meaning in the final question.